# Android NDK: custom WebView compiling from source

Tags: android, c, sdk, compilation, webview

My goal is to create a modified version of WebView (call it WebViewCustom) in Android for my personal use in my application. WebView is WebKit based so I need to compile it in C by means of NDK. I am not interested in participating in the open-source Android project now, so my need is just to be able to compile the original C source of WebView and use it as a customized control in my Android application (both SDK and NDK are possible environments for the application). I think it is possible without all that GIT WebKit stuff I am not interested in, but I am not an expert of the Android and WebKit projects. Is it possible to just edit and compile the WebView code and put it in my application as a new control? Can you show me the main steps of this task?

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I am also interesting in this approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is certainly possible. The main difficulty in rebuilding `android.webkit` from source lies in the lack of a correct build environment. It was never intended to be built outside of the target platform, but a couple of simple hacks around the sources make it quite easy to accomplish.

First of all, the whole `android.webkit` package business has to be renamed for obvious reasons, since an `android.webkit.WebView` class would already be available during runtime. Use `sed` on all the `frameworks/base/core/java/android/webkit` tree for example.

Basically you have to grab the full source tree, initialize a build environment (More information here http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html), `make framework` to make the internal runtime environment available, create a new development platform, replace all the classes from `framework.jar` (after building it's in `out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediaries/classes.jar`) into `android.jar` of the platform, build your own `webkit` package against this new platform that contains the internals.

Check out https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/ for more information on getting an internal runtime available for development purposes.

You will also need `core_intermediaries`, `bouncycastle_intermediaries` and others in order to compile `webkit`, these are all available when `make framework` is invoked, look at the errors when building your `webkit` package and grep the `out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/` to figure out which classes contain the symbols.

That's not all, however, the package uses `libwebcore.so` which exposes native methods to the `android.webkit` package; this would have to have all native method bindings registered to your new package name (in `external/webkit/WebKit/android/jni`) and be recompiled *without prelinking* (`make libwebcore`) and packaged with your application as a native library.

After everything is satisfied, you would then use your own `WebView` class from your own package instead of the `android.webkit` one. If you intend to replace `android.webview` completely - you would have to recompile a `framework.jar` and replace it inside `system/framework/` (root privileges required).

Comment: False information for now. You don't have to compile a framework.jar in /system/. As I see Dolphin Browser using it's custom WebView based on Android's but they don't touch system.

Comment: @Lazy I didn't say you had to compile framework.jar in order to use a custom WebView, you have to only do it if you intend to replace the default WebView (needs root or custom distribution).