# Android compile webkit from source and use it in an application

Tags: android

My main motivation of building my own Android webkit to minimise the rendering inconsistency of different vision of webkit on different version of android.

So far I have tried:

- downloaded the source code of android 2.2 and use (make framework) to make framework.jar and use it to replace android.jar from android SDK in a eclipse project
- changed the package name of all native methods registered in (external/webkit/WebKit/android/jni) from android.webkit to the package name of my eclipse project (com/mycustomwebkit) and then use (make libwebcore) to create the library libwebcore.so
- copied the entire webkit java class from android source(in external/webkit/WebKit/android) to my eclipse project and use it to create my own webview.
- included libwebcore.so in lib/armeabi in eclipse
- compiled and created apk file

but application crashes on launch on device with the following errors:

```
04-18 10:39:23.561: W/dalvikvm(8214): No implementation found for native Lcom/tester/webkit/JWebCoreJavaBridge;.nativeConstructor 

()V
04-18 10:39:23.561: W/dalvikvm(8214): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b4d61f8)
04-18 10:39:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(8214): FATAL EXCEPTION: WebViewCoreThread
04-18 10:39:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(8214): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nativeConstructor
04-18 10:39:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(8214):     at com.tester.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.nativeConstructor(Native Method)
04-18 10:39:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(8214):     at com.tester.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.<init>(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:66)
04-18 10:39:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(8214):     at com.tester.webkit.BrowserFrame.<init>(BrowserFrame.java:237)
04-18 10:39:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(8214):     at com.tester.webkit.WebViewCore.initialize(WebViewCore.java:236)
04-18 10:39:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(8214):     at com.tester.webkit.WebViewCore.access$1(WebViewCore.java:230)
04-18 10:39:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(8214):     at com.tester.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread$1.handleMessage

(WebViewCore.java:705)
04-18 10:39:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(8214):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-18 10:39:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(8214):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-18 10:39:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(8214):     at com.tester.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:748)
04-18 10:39:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(8214):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Am I completely in a wrong direction ? and is there a better way to minimise the rendering inconsistency of different vision of webkit on different version of android ?

Comment: See this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717257/android-ndk-custom-webview-compiling-from-source

Answer (score 2):

> So far I have tried: downloaded the source code of android 2.2 and use (make framework) to make framework.jar and use it to replace android.jar from android SDK in a eclipse project

That is not going to work. First, the classes that exist on the device will supersede the same classes in your app. Second, WebKit is not implemented in Java.

> Am I completely in a wrong direction ?

Yes.

> and is there a better way to minimise the rendering inconsistency of different vision of webkit on different version of android ?

Do not use the things that give you "rendering inconsistency of different vision of webkit on different version of android".

Or, use frameworks that have have a compatibility layer for whatever it is that you are trying to do, where they did the work of addressing the "rendering inconsistency of different vision of webkit on different version of android".

Comment: if cordova webview is used instead of the webkit.webview from the android SDK, does is help with my problem

Comment: @BillyLau: No, because `CordovaWebView` *is* the standard `WebView`, just extended with additional behaviors related to running Cordova/PhoneGap apps.

Comment: is it possible to build a new version of webkit using NDK and port it to android and then I write my own webview class in java and interface it using jni ? I notices Google have build a WebKit Chromium Port but it only support android version 4.0 or higher.

Comment: @BillyLau: Conceivably, yes. I would put the estimated level of effort on this at approximately 20 developer-years, with an assumption that a reasonable percentage of those developers have existing NDK and/or WebKit embedding experience. I hope that you have a large development team.