# No implementation found for native Ltest/webkit/JWebCoreJavaBridge;.nativeConstructor:()V

Tags: android, android-ndk, webkit

I have followed this link
[Android NDK: custom WebView compiling from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717257/android-ndk-custom-webview-compiling-from-source)
for compiling webview from source.

now i am getting this error "No implementation found for native Ltest/webkit/JWebCoreJavaBridge;.nativeConstructor:()V"

1. i have changed all package name inside external/webkit/WebKit/android/jni with my custom package names.
   e.g.

> ```
>   int registerJavaBridge(JNIEnv* env)
>     {
>         jclass javaBridge = env->FindClass("test/webkit/JWebCoreJavaBridge");
>         LOG_FATAL_IF(javaBridge == NULL, "unable to find class test/webkit/JWebCoreJavaBridge");
>         gJavaBridge_ObjectID = env->GetFieldID(javaBridge, "mNativeBridge", "I");
>         LOG_FATAL_IF(gJavaBridge_ObjectID == NULL, "Unable to find test/webkit/JWebCoreJavaBridge.mNativeBridge");
>         env->DeleteLocalRef(javaBridge);
>
>         return jniRegisterNativeMethods(env, "test/webkit/JWebCoreJavaBridge", 
>                                         gWebCoreJavaBridgeMethods, NELEM(gWebCoreJavaBridgeMethods));
>     }
> ```

Do i need to change namespace also?

2.inside java code i have tried both ways of loading lib file
System.load("libs/libwebcore.so");
or
 System.loadLibrary("webcore");

My second doubt is, my code is using system version of libwebcore.so that is present inside system/lib folder.

How to load load my version of libwebcore.so(with package name changed)?