# How to fork a Framework Library

Tags: android, android-ndk, build-process, android-framework

After downloading the [Android Source Code](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) using the `repo` command as suggested on the page:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

I was able to compile the whole project without issue using `make`.

What I would like to do is compile my own fork of `android.media.MediaPlayer`, but I am lost as to how to set up the build.

I tried using `ndk-build` in `/frameworks/base/media/libmedia`, and got the following output:

```
Android NDK: WARNING:/home/user/android/WORKING_DIRECTORY/frameworks/base/media/jni/Android.mk:media_jni: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lpthread    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: audioeffect_jni <= android_media_AudioEffect.cpp
/home/user/android/WORKING_DIRECTORY/frameworks/base/media/jni/audioeffect/android_media_AudioEffect.cpp:22:23: fatal error: utils/Log.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/home/user/android/WORKING_DIRECTORY/frameworks/base/media/obj/local/armeabi/objs/audioeffect_jni/android_media_AudioEffect.o] Error 1
```

How could I compile a `.jar` that contained `libmedia` and `android.media.MediaPlayer` so that I could simply drop it into a project and use that instead of the default `android.media.MediaPlayer`?

Comment: Well, you won't be able to "simply drop it into a project and use that instead of the default android.media.MediaPlayer?". You will need to refactor all of the classes into some new package (e.g., `dg123.media.MediaPlayer`). You cannot override framework classes from your APK. Whether you can get this to work at all is unclear, though I don't like your odds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android NDK: custom WebView compiling from source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717257/android-ndk-custom-webview-compiling-from-source)